# How can I dual-boot Ubuntu 12.04 with Windows 8?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-8, bios, secure-boot

I've been trying to dual-boot Ubuntu alongside Windows 8 on my Thinkpad T530, with no consistent success. I was able to burn the .iso image for 12.04 onto a DVD and then boot the DVD at startup, and finally install Ubuntu on a separate partition (done on Ubuntu installation Menu). I was able to explore around Ubuntu for a while, but this had to be done while SecureBoot was off. If I restarted, I wouldn't be able to access Windows 8 unless I went to BIOS and turned SecureBoot on. Once on, Windows would take me to the [this screen](http://pureinfotech.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/windows-8-dual-boot-choose-an-operating-system.png) (where the options would be Windows 8 and Ubuntu, I had tried to install Ubuntu on previous occasions, to no avail as explained above). 
Once I click Ubuntu, [this screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293840/error-message-when-booting-ubuntu-on-windows-8) appears.
If SecureBoot was off, I was able to access the [GRUB2 menu](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-DAoIzD2ZBjM/TtZHYBNRP1I/AAAAAAAAFCs/nVg15g46Zno/grub2_picture.png) and go from there to access Ubuntu. 
So... all this was yesterday. I turned my laptop on today and am not able to access Ubuntu if Secureboot is ON or OFF. Only Windows 8.

Any idea how I can fix this? I have a Ubuntu partition that I cannot access anymore, and my dual-boot screen for Windows does not work for Ubuntu. I understand that I must have done the installation for Ubuntu on my Win8 incorrectly, any way to fix this without a clean reinstall or harddrive restore?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation:**

The error message you got means you tried to install Ubuntu inside Windows (via the Wubi installer).
The problem is that Wubi is not compatible with GPT (preinstalled Windows8 are on GPT disks).

**Solution:**

Install Ubuntu the standard way, on its own partitions, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall